# Why is 'false' truthy in javascript?

Tags: javascript, casting, boolean, truthiness

I understand that an empty string is falsy in javascript and a not-empty string is truthy in javascript.

However, why is `'false'` truthy in javascript, is there anything explicit in the specification? Is it a performance issue or are there situations where you would want the string `'false'` to represent `true`?

Comment: non empty string is truthy, whatever the chars it contains

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi can you add that as the answer, a lot of answers are the what, rather than a reason why.

Comment: Note that most languages that permit "truthy"/"falsey" values for strings do *not* try to actually parse the strings. Even in Bash, where `false` is a command that always returns a non-zero error code, the double-brackets `if` construct still evaluates the string `false` as "truthy": `if [[ false ]]; then echo ha; fi`. Only Perl, which attempts to treat strings as numbers whenever such a conversion *might* make sense, actually cares what the contents of a string are when determining its "truthiness", and even there `"false"` is not considered false (`"0"` and `"undef"` are, though).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replying to the last part of your question:

> Are there situations where you would want the string 'false' to
>   represent true?

Let's consider I am testing for empty strings in my user input. To achieve that, I issue:

```
if (!theInput) {
    // Do something.
}
```

Now do I want that condition to be true if the user enters `false` in the text box? Of course, I don't.

Answer (score 10):

> is there anything explicit in the specification?

[Yes](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2):

> The result is false if the argument is the empty String (its length is zero); otherwise the result is true.

Answer (score 5):

In Javascript any string that is not empty is truthy.

So, when evaluating any non-empty string results in `true` even when the string itself is `'false'`.

You can read more about [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values.

If you want to check a string for truthness, you can check it's length.

```
var val = str.length > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of a non-empty string is always true.

`Boolean(false)` returns false

`Boolean('false')` returns true

Answer (score 1):

It's by definition. It's a string and it is handled as such. No matter the meaning of the string.

If your logic would be applied. Then how about following examples:

```
"1+3==2"
"humans have four eyes"
```

Are they also falsy?

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the Boolean values, false is false and true is true.

```
Boolean(true) //returns true
Boolean(false) //returns false
```

But when you are talking about the strings like 'true' and 'false' or any other non-empty string, Javascript will not read them as Booleans and they will be true as all other non-empty strings.

```
Boolean('true') //returns true
Boolean('false') //returns true
Boolean('blahblahblah') //returns true
```